# Pytorch: How to index a tensor?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I am new to PyTorch and am still wrapping my head around how to form a proper `gather` statement. I have a 4D input tensor of size `(1,200,61,1632)`, where `1632` is the time dimension. I want to index it with a tensor `idx` which is size `(4,1632)` where each row of `idx` is a value I want to extract from the `input` tensor. So the rows of `idx` look like:

```
[0,20,30,0]
[0,150,9,1]
[0,180,100,2]
...
```

So that the output has size `1632`. In other words I want to do this:

```py
output = []
for i in range(1632):
  output.append(input[idx[0,i], idx[1,i], idx[2,i], idx[3,i]])
```

**Is this an appropriate use case for torch.gather?** Looking at the documentation for gather, it says the input and index tensors must have the same shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PyTorch [doesn't offer](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/35674#issuecomment-881417613) an implementation of [`ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html), the ugly way of doing it is this one:

```py
output = input[idx[0, :], idx[1, :], idx[2, :], idx[3, :]]
```

In NumPy, you could do this way:

```py
output = np.take(input, np.ravel_multi_index(idx, input.shape))
```

Comment: @Ambrose no problem :) have fun